# Checking existence of char within comma seperate char list

Tags: java, string, char, comparison

I have a comma seperated String of chars, i.e.

`String charList = "A,F,3,K,X";`

And I have a char I want to compare to see if it exists within this list, i.e.

`char firstChar = 'A'`

I would like to do something like this to see if the char exists within the String, without having to a bunch of String parsing and looping:

`System.out.println(charList.contains(firstChar))`

However, the contains method needs a CharSequence and not a char. Is there a better way for me to do this besides doing my own loop and comparison:

```
boolean matches = false;
for (int i = 0; i < charList.length(); i++){
    if(firstChar == s.charAt(i)) {
        matches = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `charList.indexOf(firstChar) >= 0`.

Comment: `boolean matches = charList.indexOf(firstChar) != -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it several ways :

- Check if the `position` of the `char` is not `-1` (means don't find) [`String.indexOf(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-)

```
boolean match = charList.indexOf(firstChar) != -1;
```

- Check if the `String` `contains` the `char` (need pass from `char` to `String` with `+""`) [`String.contains(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```
boolean match = charList.contains(firstChar + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to convert a `char` to a `String`

```
charList.contains(firstChar + "")
```

Or convert using [Character.toString(char)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString-char-)

```
charList.contains(Character.toString(firstChar))
```

Or to use [String.indexOf(char)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-)

```
charList.indexOf(firstChar) >= 0
```

Using a regex with [String.matches(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) may be slight overkill for a single character, but if you have multiple it may be handy

```
charList.matches("[ABC]") //true if contains 'A', 'B', or 'C'
```

Comment: have remove the down

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
matches = charList.contains(String.valueOf(firstChar));
```